# Flash Android Device which is not switched on

Tags: android, nexus-5, usb-debugging

I want to flash OS in my Nexus5 device. I know all the commands : flashboot etc.
But the problem is that my device is not booting up, i.e. not getting switched on. Unless I reach the settinngs > enable USB debugging, the device wont show in the device list on my adb/flashboot commands. I tried all the commands to unlock but it is always saying 'waiting for device'.
I dont know how to do that : How to get my device visible without turning it on ?
PLEASE HELP!

Comment: A question suitable for XDA forums.

Comment: Place your query where you have downloaded the OS.How you are enabling usb debugging if your device is not booting up?

Comment: Thats the problem> I am not able to enable it.

Comment: May be your device bricked.

Comment: Maybe you have to see http://android.stackexchange.com/